# How does PHP as a CGI handle memory?

Tags: php, memory-management, cgi, fastcgi

When running PHP with Apache I know that the php core and all libraries are loaded for each request. However, with PHP CGI, FastCGI, or using PHP-FPM the php process persists for generally 500-1000 requests before it's restarted.

During that time, how does it handle loaded PHP classes or libraries?

**Lets say I have a file that loads a massive library, will it load (then dump) the large library every request or keep it loaded for each new request I pass it?**

By "loaded" I mean the classes are included (and parsed) but no objects are created.

How does APC play into this?

Comment: https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon/wiki/Documentation seems to be what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For FCGI (PHP-FPM is FCGI as well), only the php binary and it's binary libraries stay in memory. The PHP user-code does not.

> During that time, how does it handle loaded PHP classes or libraries?

Kicks them off, get's them new on a new request. You can easily test that by setting global variables, they are gone at the beginning of the new request.

So the answer to your (bold) question is **Let's straight-forward answer: Yes, it get's loaded and dumped per each request, no or!** :)

APC does the same. I need to research a link, there is a webserver written in PHP so it can keep everything in memory. Give's you the real speed, however your applications code must properly deal with the changed request logic then.

Comment: Nice pick. I was as well able to dig-up the webserver I refered to in my answer: [AIP - Appserver in PHP](http://blog.milkfarmsoft.com/2007/06/application-server-in-php-well%E2%80%A6-yes/). If you're interested as well in symfony, checkout these slides which combine both (plus another bundle): http://www.slideshare.net/bergie/symfony2-for-midgard-developers